# sql server update where column in (duplicate values) - how many updates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

When I do this in SQL Server

```
update table 
set column = @value
where id in (1,2,2)
```

how many updates will perform? 2 or 3, where two updates on row which id=2?

Comment: Why not just test it?

Comment: Ok, I have it, it's simple...

Comment: You can post the testcode and result as an answer and accept it later as reference for yourself and others. :)

Comment: if id is a primary key and the only primairt ket then 2.. else who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @table table (id int, num int)
insert into @table values (1,1),(2,1)

update @table
set num = num + 1
where id in (1,2,2)

select * from @table
```

Result is:

```
id  num
1   2
2   2
```

So, update will perform one time on every unique value from set.

Answer (score 2):

Test your code with a select. and you will see how many rows will be updated.

**for the count**

```
select count(*) from table
where id in (1,2,2)
```

**To see the rows being updated**

```
select * from table
where id in (1,2,2)
```

if id is a primairy key (and the only one, 2 rows )